# Breaking tweet into sub-strings and display in widget

Tags: java, android, twitter, widget, split

These days I'm trying to make a scoreboard widget for my school's cricket match. And I Already created a widget which get's messages from twitter. now i need to separate the message into pieces and display in the widget.

For Example-> when a tweet received by the widget as

```
          Home scored 50 for 8 wickets and guest scored 60 for 5 wickets and batting.
```

I want my widget to display

```
          Home = 60 wickets= 8
          Guest = 50 wickets=5 (Batting)
```

Comment: Oooh, can you give me a massage? My back is sore. `:P` (fixed spelling of message)

Comment: Your pattern is fixed?

Comment: yes.. it's more like a solid form

Comment: @doorknob srry man. bad English and new to stack overflow.

Comment: My first guess would be parsing your given String for 4 numbers, as your pattern is fixed. And then the second "and" for (additional?) batting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Home scored 50 for 8 wickets and guest scored 60 for 5 wickets and batting.";
    String result = "";
    int homeScored = s.indexOf("scored");
    int guestScored = s.lastIndexOf("scored");
    int homeWicket = s.indexOf("for");
    int guestWicket = s.lastIndexOf("for");

    result = "home =" + s.substring(homeScored + 6, homeWicket)
            + "wicket ="
            + s.substring(homeWicket + 3, s.indexOf("wickets")) + "\n"
            + "guest = " + s.substring(guestScored + 6, guestWicket)
            + "wicket ="
            + s.substring(guestWicket + 3, s.lastIndexOf("wickets"))
            + "(batting)";
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Output:

```
home = 50 wicket = 8 
guest =  60 wicket = 5 (batting)
```

Comment: thanx Achintya. That Should work.

Answer (score 1):

Using Java? Take a look at

```
String.split()
```

If your pattern is fixed you should be able to split and access the pieces by position. 
If the pattern is more dynamic, you will have to use combinations of

```
String.subString() / String.indexOf()
```

Comment: please can you explain a bit more, using the example of mine.